# Can not set static IP in wifi using wicd-curses

Tags: 14.04, networking, dhcp, ip, wicd

I configured a machine via `wicd-curses` to connect to a wifi and I checked the DHCP option. It got the IP `192.168.1.33` then it is online and can be pinged.

But when I start the machine the next day. It automatically connects to the wifi I chose but the IP becomes `192.168.0.108`. And it can't be pinged from other machine in the same LAN. So I use `wicd-curses` to re-connect it to the same wifi. After that, its IP goes back to `192.168.1.33` and it is online.

Since I don't want to do it each time I turn on the machine. I have no idea what is reason behind.

Also I checked the `/etc/network/interfaces` is the default one. I even tried to set the `wlan0` IP static there. But it seems `wicd-curses` does not apply it.

Comment: No one is interested?

Comment: It's getting 192.168.0.108 from somewhere. If its not in /etc/network/interfaces it might be from network-manager gui? or from wicd-curses (not sure how that works) or you have two dhcp servers on your LAN?